# uwp ContentControl TemplateBinding markup extension

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

The following XAML results in an error that makes no sense to me

```
<ToggleButton 
    Width="400" Height="400"
    Style="{StaticResource DieselToggleButton}"
    Margin="50, 0, 0, 0">

    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
</ToggleButton>
```

I get the following error:

> Type 'TemplateBinding' used after '{' must be a Markup Extension.
>   Error code 0x80004005.

Can somebody explain me what the problem is, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use {Binding} or {x:Bind} in your case.

Attempting to use a TemplateBinding outside of a ControlTemplate definition in XAML will result in a parser error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension